# Is it possible to use OR statement with GAE .filter()?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

For ex., if I want to search by passport id **or** by driving license id, how should I replace the following code:

```
employees.filter('passport_id =', passport_id)
employees.filter('dlicense_id =', dlicense_id)
```

Or, should I use two queries instead?

How can I merge results then?

Comment: i suggest you switch from `db` to `ndb`. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't use OR, per the [docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlreference#Syntax)

> The optional WHERE clause filters the result set to those entities
>   that meet one or more conditions. Each condition compares a property
>   of the entity with a value using a comparison operator. If multiple
>   conditions are given with the AND keyword, then an entity must meet
>   all of the conditions to be returned by the query. GQL does not have
>   an OR operator. However, it does have an IN operator, which provides a
>   limited form of OR.

Regarding your second question, here is a [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-appengine/qyrkJLAxo_g) on Google Groups that may help you with the merging of the results.

Comment: that is true only for the `db` package. `ndb` supports OR queries https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#nest_and_or